# how to show c++ code in html?

Tags: html, c++

When used with `<pre>` tag still it is not displaying `<iostream.h>`, `<conio.h>` and other keywords that contain `<>` angle brackets like "`cout<<`".
I only want to know how to display my coding on webpage. (no compilation, no syntax highlighting)

Comment: "angel bracket"? is that something God programs with?

Comment: You need to encode all html entities.

Comment: i got my answer...thanku

Comment: use this to encode the code : http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Encode.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You need to replace `<` and `>` with their [HTML character entity](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) equivalents: `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

For example:

```html
<pre>
  &lt;iostream.h&gt;
  &lt;conio.h&gt;
  cout&lt;&lt;
</pre>
```

Comment: Very nice and concise answer plus one to you!

Comment: ```using namespace std;
 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
class Subsets {
...
}
```
any alternative without converting < and > chars, html is thinking <iostream> as tag